# Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ satisfy $C^3 + 6C = 5C^2$. Prove that $C$ is diagonalizable over the real numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, diagonalization

**Question**:

Let $C \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$ satisfy $C^3 + 6C = 5C^2$.  Prove that $C$ is diagonalizable over the real numbers.

**My Attempt**:

If $C$ satisfies $C^3 + 6C = 5C^2$ then $C$ is a root of the polynomial $p(x) = x^3 - 5x^2 + 6x = x(x-2)(x-3)$.  The minimal polynomial $m(x)$ for $C$ then must divide $p(x)$.  Hence

$$
m(x) \in \{x, x-2, x-3, x(x-2), x(x-3), (x-2)(x-3), x(x-2)(x-3) \}.
$$

In any of these instances, the minimal polynomial for $C$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{R}$, and each of the possibilities for $m(x)$ has distinct roots.  This implies that the matrix $C$ will always have distinct eigenvalues, and that $C$ can be diagonalized.

**Follow up question**:

How does the value of $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ affect the proof of this solution?  For instance, if $C$ were a 5 by 5 matrix instead, would the proof still hold?

Comment: I wouldn't say the "This implies that the matrix $C$ will always have distinct eigenvalues". If you don't count multiplicity that is true for any matrix. If you count multiplicity, then it is not true for the matrices that you are considering.

Comment: Diagonalizable is what happens when the minimal polynomial is squarefree (no repeat roots).   If  the matrix satisfies a squarefree polynomial, that does it:  the minimal polynomial must then be squarefree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution is correct. Even more concisely, I think you could just say that since $p$ splits into distinct linear factors over $\mathbb{R}$, any divisor of $p$ does too (no need to explicitly list out all the possibilities for $m$).

Indeed the value of $n$ does not matter! The same argument works for $C \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ for any $n$.

Comment: Does it work for $n=1$ and $n=2$ (where $m(x)$ can't be a cubic) too?

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 0):

As long as an annihilating polynomial $a(x)=x(x-1)(x-2)$ splits into linear factors, the minimal polynomial too contains linear factors and hence the matrix $C$ is diagonalizable for all $n$.